# Highcharts Pie chart datalabels cut off/ positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm attempting to use a highcharts in conjunction with Bootstrap. The pie chart is placed inside a column of 6 for example, so it takes up half the page. What has been happening is the datalabels are too long and so are being cropped out of the containing div.
A fix that has been proposed for this is to set a width on the datalabels.
like so:

```
pie: {
            size: '60%',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            dataLabels: {
              style:{
                width:100

                color:'black'
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works flawlessly for Chrome and mozilla, the width is set and the position of the datalabel changes so its all drawn closer to the pie chart. But when testing in IE8, (and I have to account for it unfortunately) the width is set, but it appears that the position of the datalabel is not changing, so I get even less of the data label visible on the screen.

I'll try get a jsfiddle or a screenshot up shortly so you can see what I mean, but initially I was just seeing if anyone had come across this issue before, or if there's a simple fix I am just missing.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fd8X/)

I've commented out the width in the plot options so you can see what's happening. 
When I uncomment the width, it renders perfectly in Chrome and mozilla. But in IE8, the position of the label doesn't change, so the left labels end up far away from the pie chart and still cropped.

Comment: I think, you should create a jsfiddle example...

Comment: modify this example : http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi/QneV5/4/

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I've updated it with a jsFiddle.
I can't seem to load jsfiddle in ie8 at all however, even when using /draft/ in the link.

Comment: Looks likea possibly bug, reported here :https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3179